# C# 404 error ( Webclient)

Tags: c#, web, error-handling

So i have this code which i'm trying to find if Twitter / ? is in the source of the twitter.com/name ( to verify if the user exist)
When the user exist, it works fine, when the user doesn't, it gives a 404 error and stop. is there anyway to ignore the 404 error and make it still look at the source code of that page? because if we go to ex: view-source:https://twitter.com/pogosode , it doesn't exist but we can still see the source..

```
foreach (Membre noms in p_nom)
        {
            string websiteName = "https://twitter.com/" + noms.NomMembre;
            string source = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(websiteName);
            if (source.Contains("<title>Twitter / ?</title>"))
                {
                p_disponible.Add(new MembreVerifier(noms.NomMembre));
                }
        }
```

Comment: Twitter has an API designed for this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search

Comment: Why not just detect the 404 error and drive the logic from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the WebException exception and read the response from the Response property.

Example:

```
foreach (Membre noms in p_nom)
{
    string source = "";
    try
    {           
        string websiteName = "https://twitter.com/" + noms.NomMembre;
        source = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(websiteName);     
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Copy stream to buffer.
            var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);

            // Decode byte array to UTF-8 string.
            source = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }

    if (source.Contains("<title>Twitter / ?</title>"))
    {
         p_disponible.Add(new MembreVerifier(noms.NomMembre));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, the only thing is that i've made and else{*do something*} for when the source doesn't contain the twitter / ? but it doesn't do the things in the else

Comment: It is beacuse when an exception occurs (as it will when you get a 404) execution of the code will stop and the program jumps to the catch part. So you will have to modify your logic to account for that.

Comment: Yea, i've added that :  // TODO: Use content.
                        if (content.Contains("<title>Twitter / ?</title>"))
                        {
                            //p_disponible.Add(new MembreVerifier(noms.NomMembre));
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} is available for twitter.", noms.NomMembre);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Too bad! {0} isn't available for twitter.", noms.NomMembre);
                        }
into the catch and the else doesn't work :O

Comment: I've changed the code to better fit your purpose.